# How to solve the problem of uninstalling MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to uninstall MySQL on ubuntu OS 20.04 LTS, but when I run this command :

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
```

I get this error output :

```
kabouri@kabouri:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql*
[sudo] password for kabouri: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-source-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltcl' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-apt-config' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-router' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-sandbox' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltuner' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Package 'mysql-client-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-sandbox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltcl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltuner' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-router' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-source-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-apt-config* mysql-client* mysql-client-8.0* mysql-client-core-8.0* mysql-common* mysql-server* mysql-server-8.0*
  mysql-server-core-8.0* phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 231 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 487840 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.postrm: 144: .: Can't open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: general debugging tip: try removing the packages one at a time or at least a few at a time to help track down which package is creating the issue

Comment: Instead of purge, try remove. `sudo apt-get remove "mysql*"`

Comment: I try that but no result.